# How does Parallels allow you to access your camera and microphone on the M1 Macbook?

Tags: virtualization, qemu, parallels, macbook-air

I have been trying to pass through my camera and microphone to my Arch VM on my M1 Macbook Air via QEMU to no avail. However, just to check if it was possible, I tried Parallels and it worked right out of the box with an Ubuntu install. So, how do they do it?

Interestingly enough, VirtualBox can see my webcam with `VBoxManage list webcams`.